# python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm fails using spacy 3.0.3

Tags: spacy

Why am I getting this error `AttributeError: module 'srsly' has no attribute 'read_yaml'`

when I attempt `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

I've been following the instructions here [Install spaCy](https://spacy.io/usage)

Comment: Are you installing it on Windows? With admin privileges?

Comment: Yes to both, thanks.

Comment: You probably started installing spacy without admin rights first, then tried to install with admin rights. Then, you need to uninstall one package (not sure it is actually `srsly`), and re-install it.

Comment: I just reverted to an older set of libraries and incrementally updated what I needed minimally.  All set now.

Answer (score 2):

I was using an earlier version of `srsly` which gave me this issue. Fixed it by upgrading it to latest version

```
pip install -U srsly
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. Solved it by doing

```
pip uninstall spacy
pip install spacy 2.3.2
```

Its maybe a bug due to the latests versions of spacy